# Extend notebook monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to find out if there are any small monitors out there that I could add to the side of my notebook. This may sound a bit bizarre, here is an image that will kind of show what I mean 
[image]

That is built in but it's something similar with what I would like to achieve.
I can't add a big monitor because I don't have the necessary space and something like that in the image would help a lot. Just to keep the reference manuals and such. I'm so damn tired of alt+tab every minute.

I'm also opened to other options!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just so you're clear, the W700ds/701ds have that screen recessed, it doesn't just fold over or what have you.  You'll probably be looking, at best, at something that clips on that you'll have to detach constantly.  Are you going to be doing this mobile on a regular basis?  It seems like it would be a huge pain to use outside home/office, especially if it's not a perfect fit...and at that point you're better off just hooking up an extra monitor.

Comment: You say that you don't have the space. Will you be using the extra monitor on a desk? Do you need it to be mobile? If you're using it on a desk that may just be small, consider getting a widescreen monitor and rotating it for a tall screen monitor. Many people find it very useful. http://bit.ly/cl5Bcx

Answer (score 1):

[ThinkGeek](http://www.thinkgeek.com/) sells a few that [connect via USB](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/usb-gadgets/).